# How do I share Gradle scripts between repositories?

Tags: repository, gradle, share

We have two repositories for Java components, from which we need to produce a WAR. The Gradle build scripts in those repositories have many common parts. 
How should we share those common Gradle scripts between the repositories:
- Put common Gradle scripts into repository;
- Have a custom Gradle distribution, put it into repository?
Any other ideas?
If we put common Gradle scripts into repository, we also will need to put them in SCM, and keep them in sync - we will probably need another Gradle script to publish Gradle scripts to repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to share build logic between builds:

1. Write a build script containing the shared logic (e.g. `foo.gradle`), put it up on a web server, and include it in other builds with `apply from: "http://..."`. We call this a *script plugin*.
2. Make a separate plugin project (and build), write a binary plugin (a class implementing `org.gradle.api.Plugin`), publish it as a Jar to a repository, and include it in other builds with `apply plugin: ...` and a `buildscript {}` section.

A limitation of script (but not binary) plugins is that they aren't cached. Therefore, a build that makes use of script plugins will only succeed if it can connect to the web server that's serving the plugins.

For further details, see the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and the many samples in the full Gradle distribution.